# Apache htaccess change 404 to 200?

Tags: http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I like to know if posible to change the 404 HTTP Status code into 200 for a specific file.

If that posible how can I do it ? Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more specific about your need:

- Does the file exist in filesystem? HTTP response status for regular file is 200 by default.
- If the file exists - why are you getting 404s now? Are you using some sort of mod-rewrite rules?

Comment: ok. I have a wordpress installation. The problem is that while the home page (index.php) is served correctly and the content too, the HTTP Status Code is 404. What I like to do, if that is posible is to change from within the htaccess that status code to 200. Is it posible ? :?

Comment: @Merianos Nikos No -- you have to do it from within index.php, as .htaccess you cannot alter HTTP Status Code via .htaccess when page/script was executed.

Comment: What a weird issue: So your browser gets a 404 response, stating that the file doesnt exist, but is still able to pick it up since it's there? How did you even notice the wrong status if everything appears fine :) Thing is: htaccess cant do this for you, you need to use header(); (Assuming you use php)